# Применение модификаторов virtual/override

Tags: c#

Приведите, пожалуйста, хотя бы один реальный пример использования модификаторов virtual/override, где модификаторы virtual/ovveride оказываются действительно необходимы, и их нельзя заменить модификатором new.

Comment: перегрузка ToString()

Comment: можно ссылку на пример

Comment: настрочил ответ

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Предположим, есть 2 класса

```
public class MyOverrideObject
{
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return "-->Overrided<--";
    }
}

public class MyNewObject
{
    public new string ToString()
    {
        return "-->NEW<--";
    }
}
```

И код вывода в консоль

```
Console.WriteLine("{0}\n{1}", new MyOverrideObject(), new MyNewObject());
```

Вывод

```
-->Overrided<--
UserQuery+MyNewObject
```

Как видно, скрытие метода не сработало, так как консоль не знает о конкретных типах, что в неё отправили и не проверяет этого. 
По сути везде, где принимающий класс не в курсе точного типа аргумента, скрытие метода работать не будет. Потому использовать его я крайне не рекомендую.

Comment: Почему вызывается метод ToString? DotPeek это не показывает.

Comment: @Alex_ этот метод вызывает ужа сама консоль, когда формирует строку для вывода. Но так как консоль не с курсе сокрытия методов и реального типа аргумента, вызывается ToString от типа object

Comment: А когда нужно использовать new?

Comment: @Alex_ 10 лет пишу на C#, ни разу не приходилось использовать new

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ!

Comment: @Alex_ пожалуйста